# How to get random string in txt file (c++ ifstream)?

Tags: c++, qt, file, fstream, txt

For example I have txt db's with word list (in screen) I need output random 3 line in this file in `ifstream` C++. I tried this in `for` loop, but it's very consumably

[image]

```
#include "gamewindow.h"
#include "ui_gamewindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <QLabel>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
string login;
bool start_is_clicked=false;
GameWindow::GameWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::GameWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ifstream logined("last_login.txt");
    getline(logined,login);
    QString qstring_login = QString::fromLocal8Bit(login.c_str());
    ui->login_label->setText(qstring_login);
    logined.close();
}

GameWindow::~GameWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
int countStringsWords(){
    string current;
    int count = 0;
    ifstream words("word_db.txt");
    do{
        getline(words,current);
        count++;
    }while(!words.eof());
    words.close();
    return count;
}
void getLabelText(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    ifstream words("word_db.txt");
    int start=rand()%countStringsWords();
    words.close();
    cout<<start<<endl;
}
void GameWindow::on_Start_stop_clicked()
{
    if(ui->Start_stop->text()=="START"){
        ui->Start_stop->setText("STOP");
        getLabelText();
    }
    else if(ui->Start_stop->text()=="STOP"){
        ui->Start_stop->setText("START");
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Button error"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Work area:

```
int countStringsWords(){
    string current;
    int count = 0;
    ifstream words("word_db.txt");
    do{
        getline(words,current);
        count++;
    }while(!words.eof());
    words.close();
    return count;
}
void getLabelText(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    ifstream words("word_db.txt");
    int start=rand()%countStringsWords();
    words.close();
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have already written.

Comment: just added, check.

Comment: could you add a working example? (with as few include as possible)

Comment: just added, too

Comment: @Bogdan I believe what Riccardo was asking for is a working, portable example that we can put into our own environment to debug/test.

Comment: I added answer of his question in Work Area: ...

Comment: What is the variable "start" in getLabelText()? The file word_db.txt is opened inside the function getLabelText(), then called the function countStringsWords() (to count the number of lines) in which the same text file is opened, counted and closed. Is this odd process necessary?

Answer (score 1):

### Upgrading your current solution:

What you could do is use a dynamic list (vector) to fill the vector with the file, then generate 3 random indexes and return an array of those three random strings. If the length of the text file is n, this would be an O(n) space and time complexity.

#### Is there a Better Solution?

If you want O(1) time and space complexity (disregarding file storage on your device) then I would recommend making the file an XML file, as this would allow you to access the file at any index natively, meaning you would not need to load the entire file into an array, which is not recommended for larger files.

```
int * ReturnRandomWords(){
    std::string current;
    vector<std::string> WordsFromFile
    ifstream words("word_db.txt");
    do{
        getline(words,current);
        WordsFromFile.push(current);
    }while(!words.eof());
    words.close();
    string v1 = WordsFromFile.at( rand() % WordsFromFile.size());  
    string v2 = WordsFromFile.at( rand() % WordsFromFile.size());   
    string v3 = WordsFromFile.at( rand() % WordsFromFile.size()));
    string arr [3] = {v1, v2, v3};
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i just don`t entered correct filename in variable ifstream words xD

Answer (score 0):

To add onto ZanyCactus' answer.

If you need each answer to be unique and can use C++17 you can use `std::sample`:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> random_words;
constexpr size_t number_of_random_words = 3;
std::sample(
    WordsFromFile.begin(),
    WordsFromFile.end(),
    std::back_inserter(random_words),
    number_of_random_words,
    std::default_random_engine(std::random_device()())
);
```

Comment: thanks, but i just don`t entered correct filename in variable ifstream words xD